# do we have any result proving a strong upper bound on the cardinality of set $P_{\alpha}(x)$ for some large parameter $x$?

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Define $x_0=0$ and $x_{i+1} = F(x_i)$ for all integers $i \ge 0$, where $F(x)$ is a polynomial with integral coefficients such that $x_{i}\rightarrow\infty$ as $i$ grows large.
Suppose $l(p)$ is the least positive integer such that $p|x_{l(p)}$ for some prime $p$.

Then if we let
$$P_{(0<\alpha<1)} = \{ p\in \mathbb{P}\mid l(p)<p^{\alpha}\}$$ where $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of primes and also $P_{\alpha}(x)$ is the set of primes belonging to $P_{\alpha}$ which are less than $x$ , do we have any result proving a strong upper bound on the cardinality of set $P_{\alpha}(x)$  for some large parameter $x$?

In particular, I want to know if for $\alpha=\frac{1}{2+\epsilon}$ we have $P_{\alpha}(x)=O(\frac{x}{(\log{x})^{1+\gamma}})$ for two constants $\epsilon>0$ and $\gamma>0$?

**P.S Sorry MO users my earlier post had some errors so I am reposting it.**

Comment: Depends on $F$. For example if $F(x)=xG(x)$ then your sequence consists of $0$s. So $l(p)=1$ for every $p$.

Comment: See carefully I have already said that $x_{i}\rightarrow\infty$ so you can't choose such F

Comment: You did assume that $x_i\to \infty$. You did not define $P_\alpha(x)$.Take $F(x)=x+1$. Then $x_n=n$. So $l(p)=p$ and $P_\alpha$ is empty for every $\alpha<1$. Since you did not define $P(x)$ it is not clear what the answer is  in that case.

Comment: I have included the definition

Comment: I am sure that for non-linear $F$ nothing non-trivial is known. Try $F(x)=2x^2+1$, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out already in the comments, you need extra assumptions to ensure that you get the behavior you want. I shall comment under such assumptions.

Consider the simplest case of $F$ a linear polynomial, say for instance $F_e(x):=ex+(e-1)$ for a fixed $e \in \mathbb N$. Then you are asking for the multiplicative order $\ell_e(p)$ of $e$ modulo $p$.

In this case, the answer is that your ansatz is known under GRH, otherwise there is no known way to go beyond the $1/2$ exponent.

The best paper to reference for this is [Kurlberg&Pomerance 2004](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0405120.pdf). In the first pages, they survey known results on $P_\alpha(x)$. The best unconditional theorem gives the bound for $\alpha=1/2-o(1)$, while for $1/2-\varepsilon$ you need RH for certain Kummer extensions; the closest to what you are seeking is I believe in [Pappalardi](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.8.6190&rep=rep1&type=pdf), but the methods trace back to Hooley's work on Artin's conjecture.

So, although nothing is known besides these $F$, the natural guess would of course be that for any reasonable $F$ you can get as far as $1/2-o(1)$ unconditionally and prove your desired bound under some form of RH. Still, extending the result from the "Artin" setting of multiplicative orders to the cousin problem of iterates of polynomials would be an absolutely noteworthy task and by no means easy. To search for other works that prove the basic results and analogies, you can start from [my survey](http://www.seminariomatematico.polito.it/rendiconti/78-1/Tron.pdf) (last section).

Comment: If I am not wrong the biggest hurdle is due to the fact that $l(p)$ has no relation with $p-1$

Comment: @Emanuele Tron however in the paper on terms n dividing nth term of linear recurrence by luca and others,in the lemma 2.1 they show an upper bound for any exponent and hence I thought that such bounds could be proven for this case however as superguy has said due to those restrictions we cant proceed in known ways

Comment: Also note that finding a bound of the quality you want lies further ahead still than finding just any bound for a generic $F$. The lemma in Alba Gonzalez et al. does not go at all beyond the $1/2$ barrier, it's just a generalization of a folklore argument.

Comment: Ya I got you but I just wanted to say that for the linear case as you showed we can obtain that bound I stated as shown in lemma 2.1 of that paper

Comment: This was what I meant Like in $F_e(x)$ if we choose $\alpha=0.33$ then $P_α(x)=O(\frac{x^{\frac{2}{3}}}{logx})$ by lemma 2.1 which is stronger than what I want but all this is applicable only for linear cases

Comment: It seems that you have mistook the inequality $l(p)<p^{\alpha}$ with $l(p)>p^{\alpha}$

Comment: I see your point. But I think the directions in the bounds are the right ones. Take for instance Pappalardi: $\ell(p)>p^{1/2}\exp((\log p)^\delta)$ for all but $O(x/\log^{1+\gamma} x)$ primes. It just seems that most results focus on improving, in a sense, on $\alpha$ rather than $\gamma$. In any case there is nothing like that known for non-linear $F$, the obstacle being of course the lack of techniques in the literature; I had listed the few analogous result that I know of for iterates of polynomials at the end of my survey.